# Setting several fonts in Latex Overleaf

Tags: fonts, fontspec, overleaf

I am trying to create a document using my company's own font. There are 4 ttf-extension fonts: normal, bold, italic, and bold-italic. How can I use all of them in my document and have the section titles be displayed correctly in bold?

Right now when I use either XeLatex or LuaLatex together with

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{[MyFont.ttf]}
```

I just get the standard font for all of my text.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `\setmainfont[BoldFont=MyBold.ttf]{MyFont.ttf}`

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you. This does not change the section titles to bold, however.

Comment: If I skip `\usepackage{fontspec}`, i get this in the title of my document "[BoldFont=DINOffc-Bold.ttf, BoldItalicFont=DINOffc-BoldIta.ttf, ItalicFont=DINOffc-
Ita.ttf, ]DINOffc.ttf"

Comment: no, if you skip `\usepackage{fontspec}` you get an error that `\setmainfont` is not defined. If you choose to scroll past any error, the pdf you get is not intended to be usable, just a debugging aid.

Comment: Please post your code as `MWE`, what you tried so far

Comment: section titles may or may not be bold, depending whether the document class you are using specifies bold headings.